# Converting this XMLList to XML

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var xml:XML  = new XML( 
<root>
<message for="Harry" > adlfjljfa </message> 
<message for="Harry" > ajf ja; jafja </message>
<message for="Akil"> difasfjlfjals </message> 


var xmlList:XMLList = xml.message.(@for== "Harry" ) 

var nameXML:XML = XML(xmlList) 


trace( nameXML )
```

Right now the nameXML doesnot form correctly, and throws an error : The markup in the document following the root element must be well formed.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you don't have a closing `<root>` and `for` is reserved word

Answer (score 1):

You didnt close the `root` tag in the XML declaration.

I replaced the "for" attribute because its reserved.

```
var xml:XML  =
<root>
<message dest="Harry" > adlfjljfa </message> 
<message dest="Harry" > ajf ja; jafja </message>
<message dest="Akil"> difasfjlfjals </message> 
</root>

var xmlList:XMLList = xml.message.(@dest== "Harry" ) 

for each (var item:XML in xmlList) {
 trace(item)    
}
```

**output**

```
adlfjljfa
ajf ja; jafja
```

**Edit**

You can also keep the "`for`" attribute :

```
var xmlList:XMLList = xml.message.(attribute('for')== "Harry" )
```

Comment: yep , but may be you know how can we still use a "for" word , something like `message.attributes("for")` or similar ?

Comment: But how to store it in XML ? ( It could be stored in XML without error if there would be a single "Harry" ). But because there are two "Harry" , the XML is not formed correctly.

Comment: I think you need to do something like `var newXml:XML = XML('<root>' + xmlList.toString() + '</root>');`

Comment: xmlList in this case is a type of array xmlList[0] and xmlList[1] consist of two nodes. So concatenation won't work here.

Comment: Well toString() convert it to a string, concat works, try you will see.